# What is the best philosophy joke you have heard

Tags: untagged

I am not talking about jokes about how poor philosophers are or how unpractical they are.  But one of those jokes that really makes you think. And would be appropriate to tell in class.  Interested to hear what people think.

Comment: I voted to close because I see this as primarily opinion based.  However, I hope you come back with other questions.  And, in spite of the vote to close, I would love to hear such jokes.  I just don't think they are what this site is for, but others may not agree with me.

Comment: [Questions like “What’s your favorite ______?” are explicitly discouraged](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Depending on your actual motivation, you might be able to revise the question into something more suitable. For example, explicitly stating your motivation: what you hope to accomplish by being armed with such jokes.

Comment: @FrankHubeny, other SE sites have similar questions. E.g. what is the funniest paper you ever read. But they were posted as community wiki.

Comment: @Hurkyl, "And would be appropriate to tell in class." That's the answer what he wants to do armed with such jokes.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3682/2953

Comment: @rus9384 each site has their own culture. Just because something is allowed on certain sites doesn't mean it's allowed on every site. Based on the above meta discussion, it seems this is not allowed here.

Comment: @AndrewT. They were not allowed there as well...

Comment: From McEwen’s novel Solar: a string theorist, caught by his wife in a compromising situation with another woman, tries to reassure her: ‘‘Darling, I can explain everything.’’ [could equally substitute a philosopher with the same ambitions]

Answer (score 4):

### [Bruces' Philosophers Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9SqQNgDrgg)

Music and Lyrics: [Eric Idle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Idle)

> [Imannuel Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant) / was a real piss ant / who was [very rarely stable](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-reason/)
>
> [Heidegger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger) Heidegger / was a boozy beggar / who could think you under the table
>
> [David Hume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hume) / could out-consume / [Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._W._F._Hegel)
>
> And [Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) / was a beery swine / who was just as sloshed as [Schlegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Wilhelm_Friedrich_Schlegel)
>
> There's nothing [Nietzsche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche) couldn't teach ya 'bout the raising of the wrist
>
> [Socrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) himself was permanently [pissed](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pissed)

-

> [John Stuart Mill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stuart_Mill) / of [his own free will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Liberty) / on half a pint of [shandy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shandy) was particularly ill
>
> [Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato) they [say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symposium) / could stick it away / half a crate of whiskey every day
>
> [Aristotle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristotle) Aristotle / was a bugger for the bottle / [Hobbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hobbes) was fond of his [dram](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dram)
>
> And [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) / was a drunken fart / ["I drink, therefore I am"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)
>
> Yes Socrates himself is particularly missed / a lovely little thinker but a bugger when he's pissed.

Assignment for the class: find all the philosophy references made in connection to the philosophers in the song.

### Bonus joke

Descartes is tending a bar.

Client walks in and says "I think I will have a free beer, on the house"

Descartes — mightily annoyed at this rude suggestion — exclaims: "I think not!"

...and promptly disappears.

Comment: @MichaekK. +1. I've never liked Bruce's song but your Bonus joke made me laugh out loud. A good start to the day (UK : 08.05). Best - Geoff.

Comment: the mostly German philosophers song: https://youtu.be/w0shWISKpNA

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is strictly a philosophy joke, since you could easily replace the philosopher with any complex profession.  In any case, here is a great joke that was [Number 4 on the *Psychology Today* top-ten philosophy jokes](https://www.psychologytoday.com/au/blog/hide-and-seek/201303/top-10-philosophy-jokes):

> A renowned philosopher was held in high regard by his driver, who listened in awe as his boss lectured and answered difficult questions about the nature of things and the meaning of life.  Then, one day, the driver approached the philosopher and asked if he was willing to switch roles for just one evening. The philosopher agreed, and, for a while, the driver handled himself remarkably well.
>
> However, when the time came for questions, someone at the back of the room asked him, "Is the epistemological meta-narrative that you seem to espouse compatible with a teleological account of the universe?"
>
> "That's an extremely simple question," he replied. "So simple, in fact, that even my driver could answer it."

Answer (score 3):

There's a choice :

Bertrand Russell : 'The law of causality, I believe, like much that passes muster among philosophers, is a relic of a bygone age, surviving, like the monarchy, only because it is erroneously supposed to do no harm.' (Mysticism and Logic, IX, 'On the Notion of Cause', London : George Allen & Unwin, 1917, 180.

Bertrand Russell : 'So far, there is nothing particularly frepugnant to our prejudices in the conclusion of the benabourists. We are all willing to admit that other people are thoughtless.' (The Analysis of Mind, Lecture I, London : George Allen & Unwin, 1921, 21.

Gilbert Ryle : '... Professor A.C. Campbell, who has written several books on the freedom of will - or rather, one book several times' (Oxford lecture, 1967).

Peter Strawson : '... like self-mutilation, which starts off as merely painful and ends as logically impossible' (Oxford lecture, 1968).